# Thymeleaf HTML <i> Tag

Tags: css, html, thymeleaf

I have this HTML <i> Tag defined in my template, that is replacing the style color property for the bean property. But is not replacing the color for the Bean property

```
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" style="color:'${book.htmlIconColor}'; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: What does "not working proper[l]y" mean? Do you not see the icon? Is it the wrong color? Does it print rude words instead?

Comment: Remove the single quotes？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `th:style` which generates the style attribute.

```
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" 
   th:style="'color:' + ${book.htmlIconColor} + '; text-align: center;'" 
   aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

or alternate method

```
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" 
   th:style="${'color:' + book.htmlIconColor + '; text-align: center;'}" 
   aria-hidden="true"></i>
```